# Changing Permalinks

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I want to change my permalinks from /%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/ to /%postname%/

but when I added the following to the .htaccess file, posts didn't redirect the way I thought they would:

RedirectMatch 301 /dddd/dd/dd/(.*) /$1

What do I need to put into my .htaccess file to make it work?

My site is http://SweatingTheBigStuff.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think everyone is missing the point here - I think @Daniel has *changed* his permalinks, and now wants to redirect *old permalinks*.

The problem is your RedirectMatch regex is only matching a literal 'd', not digits.

Personally I would use this instead;

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/(.+)$ /$1
```

**However**, @markratledge is right in saying that there are issues with using just the postname.

Answer (score 1):

You don't go into any code to change permalinks; that's changing WP core files, you'll break things and you'll loose your changes on an upgrade. It's much easier than that: go to Wordpress/Dashboard/Setings/Permalinks. If your .htaccess isn't writable, you'll get a warning.

And, using only the postname in permalinks is not recommended for performance reasons: [Using only Postname in Permalinks « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Using_only_.25postname.25)

Comment: So what is the best permalink structure? I prefer not to use the date (I want to use the old post promoter plugin and the date makes it incompatible).

Answer (score 0):

A relevant answer to TheDeadMedic,

You could use a plugin called [Redirection](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection/) to redirected your old permalinks to new permalinks.

But if you need to change your permalinks from the old version to a new version, then follow markratledge's advice